# php find to array and convert to variable

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, sorting

I have a function that connects to facebok sdk.

This function retuns an array posted below.

I'd like to find a specific varriable within that array and sub-arrays and store it to MySQL.

I need to search for this index: `[name] => Riad Flam and all sub ( ex toke,id,...)` and store it into MySQL.

This is the returned array :

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Local business
                    [category_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 164243073639257
                                    [name] => Hotel
                                )
                        )
                    [name] => Riad Flam
                    [access_token] => BAAGeBYlwA38BALZAddqsUR2na13zh40E1F7YQMKGiga6fVIzkqBt3RW5r5vTIl3Qnb8lLhZBMk8yNAcRZCp8FDpgGr4ZCagHU1yqJ1w2oUklgAwlZAgJotHYZCJQcw2g1H5uZCdtdhcLwGwLZA2FfEFRGBUgUKvs2a1LJIDFab3vXoS1srbqnZA1cztIH5iyqZB7dEGEXxNEPzMdcvGZCZAw8nuWZCECwkE2WAy0ZD
                    [id] => 124602074303943
                    [perms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ADMINISTER
                            [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                            [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                            [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                            [4] => CREATE_ADS
                            [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Energy/utility
                    [name] => Ewaa
                    [access_token] => BAAGeBYlwA38BAFWlnftqfUpM0nT3i9OG6BxDHhcoVQEZAsPciUce4zZA2ywWX6LrzlLMXZA24wBRHmG60wZCYSEG0J9kdPTAUnQD9kLMgdDYup1ZBJcji4mzCS2ltJmpGbBCsglcZBwjix8Vl5bhUrOu3o1hZBA6SBsOE9ZC1SZAeJZANdvA0OV2myj4yYEcVvZBinyyzGUhRH3TtYWEb4zfmFfaZAyau9Np2agZD
                    [id] => 239767479474629
                    [perms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ADMINISTER
                            [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                            [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                            [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                            [4] => CREATE_ADS
                            [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
                        )
                )
```

Comment: foreach() and string comparison?

Comment: @RoyalBg: Hats off to U man...! U understood this question???

Comment: Yeah, but on second thought, maybe not, so, he wants to retrieve the data from the same key where this `name` is?

Comment: can you give a exemple ? i have try many solution ...

this is my code to retur array

$facebook = new Facebook($app_config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){
  try{
    $accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($accounts);
    echo '</pre>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess You need something like this:

```
foreach($return['data'] as $item) {
    /* PSEUDO CODE: */
    $db->insert($item['name']); // just write the insert into function here using $item['name'] as the value to insert
}
```

**Edit:**

```
foreach($return['data'] as $item) {
    /* PSEUDO CODE: */
    if($item['name'] == 'insert only this item') {
        $db->insert($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank this code work the probleme now is : 

how i cant fiand and store only ex: $item['name'] where is = name riad flam and all sub key ? 
name,id,token ?


how i can put code in stackoverfolw response ... ctrl+k don't work

Comment: HU .. i have not try this way but for me is a loop ... ( foreach ) and .. nop is good. Yous save my live thanks   !!! 

now i can store token from facebook for long times